# How to soundproof door with vents?

Tags: sound-proofing

My current apartment has a washer and drier behind a vented door. Obviously this lets a lot of noise passing through. What would be the best way for me to temporarily soundproof this door?

Here are a couple pictures of said door:

[image]
[image]

Requirements are:

- Needs to be removable without too much visible damages
- Needs to be fireproof, I guess?

Thank you all in advance :)

Comment: Why would it need to be fireproof? That door certainly isn't.

Comment: True. I guess I thought a foam fabric could help but was wondering whether it could be a fire hazard with the machines insides that space. Maybe not at all. I don’t have the experience to judge :)

Comment: Does the room have a ventilator? Both dryer and washer can produce heat, and it's going to turn into a steam room if you block it off. Sound proof is typically somewhat air-proof too, and will definitely reduce ventilation.

Comment: Good point. The room does not have a ventilator on any wall. Also worth noting, there is a Grinell head on the ceiling. I guess that’s why it is a vented door and maybe soundproofing it isn’t a great idea.

Comment: It's probably vented for a reason. I have a stacked washer and dryer in a closet, where I vented the door to meet the manufacturer's instruction. Leveling the machines and putting some kind of dampening mat below them is probably your only option.

Comment: Is the dryer gas or electric?

Comment: I doubt the washer dryer stack needs venting. The ones in apartments, especially those in a closet are ventless systems. 
Double check to see if they are and if it is you can proceed with what you were going to do. 
I would just put up a new door.

Comment: I believe the drier is electric.

It is probably ventless system indeed as there is no vents anywhere inside this closet. Putting up a new door means I have to store the current one, which I can’t. I’m more looking for a temporary solution I can undo later on.